# Search for content by title or add edit link to node

Tags: nodes

I have a Drupal 7 installation with a lot of content and it seems quite limiting that I cannot filter the content in the content administration screen by title. Is there a plugin that will add a filter to the title? I haven't found one so far after a lot of searching.

Alternatively the ability to add an edit link (near the nodequeue add/remove links) would be very useful. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's the [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module, which replaces a bunch of the default admin pages with configurable views:

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for superior usability.

Features:

> - Filter all administrative views via AJAX.
> - Perform any kind of bulk/mass operations on items in administrative views.
> - **Filter content by title**, node type, author, published status, and/or vocabulary.
> - Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
> - Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.

You'll also need the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) for this

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! I've been searching for 2 days now and managed to completely miss that somehow!

Comment: How do you make administration view take over admin/content?